# IOs Autolayout top position

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I've a problem with my layout and don't find suggestions to solve.
My scenario is:

I've 2 views (a UIImageView and a UILabel) side by side and with dynamic height and I need to put another view bellow the tallest of the two views.

This image illustrates my problem, but I'm creating that views programmatically.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRSib.png

These are my constraints:

```
H:|-8-[UIImageView]-8-[Label1]-8|
V:|-8-[UIImageView]
V:|-8-[Label1]
H:|-8-[Label2]-8|
V:[UIImageView]-(>=8)-[Label2]
V:[Label1]-(>=8)-[Label2]
```

I know that my layout is ambiguous, but I can't to solve this.

Thanks for help

Comment: It may be easiest to put your UIImageView and Label1 inside of a UIView. Scale this containter UIView to fit its contents and constrain the top of Label2 to the bottom of the container.

Comment: Hi Alex,
Thanks for your help. 
In the moment I can't do this. This scenario is built with the content downloaded from webservice, and I can't change the webservice to send this information to create a new view to put other views inside.
Do you know other alternative to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add constraints with priorities and you need an additional constraint. Your current spec is ambiguous because there are multiple potential solutions.

The 2 constraints to position the `Label2` based on the heights need to be high priority (the default). You also need another constraint of a low priority which tells the layout system what you prefer - I.e. That the y position should be the maximum, because the low priority constraint specifies that the label should be pinned to the bottom of the container / a static value larger then the possible heights of the other views.

The visual constraint language is a convenience but it doesn't allow you to specify everything.

Comment: Wain, thanks.
I understand your explanation, but I don't know how to create these constraints.
Could you give-me a pratical example based on my problem?

Tks

Comment: Look at using something like https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout and see the included examples. Set the priorities on the returned constraints.